# Primes Number Sequence

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Find the pattern in the sequence:

> 10 11 21 247 29 391 ? ? ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next three numbers are:

> 1271, 47, 1591

The pattern:

> Let $a_i$ denote the $i$-th number in the sequence, $p_i$ denote the $i$-th prime number.
>
>  We have
>  $a_1 = 10 = 2 \times 5 = p_1 \times p_3 $
>  $a_2 = 11 = p_5 $
>  $a_3 = 21 = 3 \times 7 = p_2 \times p_4 $
>  $a_4 = 247 = 13 \times 19 = p_6 \times p_8 $
>  $a_5 = 29 = p_{10} $
>  $a_6 = 391 = 17 \times 23 = p_7 \times p_9 $
>
>  Therefore for $i \ge 0$:
>  $a_{3i+1} = p_{5i+1} \times p_{5i+3}$
>  $a_{3i+2} = p_{5i+5}$
>  $a_{3i+3} = p_{5i+2} \times p_{5i+4}$
>
>  Plug $2$ into $i$ we can get:
>  $a_7 = p_{11} \times p_{13} = 31 \times 41 = 1271$
>  $a_8 = p_{15} = 47$
>  $a_9 = p_{12} \times p_{14} = 37 \times 43 = 1591$